# GuzzleHttp - Get JSON encoded body

Tags: json, api, laravel-5.3, guzzle

I created an API client for my company to fetch orders from our distributors. I need to acknowledge download of orders back to them with a PUT. The PUT is working properly but I get an error on their confirmation of my acknowledgement.
Using Postman, I get a JSON body message back.

When I PUT a acknowledgement back, I get the following error:

```
    Type error: Argument 1 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::send() must 
    implement interface Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface, instance of 
    GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response given, called in 
    /var/www/orders/app/Http/Controllers/edi/OrderController.php on line 86
```

This is line 86:

```
    $response = $client->send($apirequest);
```

The relevant code:

```
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
    use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleHttpClient;
    use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
    use Response;
    use XmlParser;
    use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;

    public function orderConfirm()
    {
    $uri = config('services.orders.orderack');

    $formdata = Input::all();
    $orders = Input::get('orders');

    try {
        $client = new GuzzleHttpClient([
            'headers'=> [
                'Authorization' => '$user',
                'ContractID' => '$contract',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json']
            ]);

        $apirequest = $client->request('PUT', $uri,
            ['body' => json_encode(
                [
                    $orders
                ]
            )]
        );

        $response = $client->send($apirequest);
        $contents = (string) $response->getBody();

        return $contents;

    }
    catch (RequestException $ex) {
        //Exception Handling
        echo $ex;
    }
```

Output from Postman was:

```
    "Number of Orders Acknowledged: 1"
```

from other posts on SO, this:

```
     $contents = (string) $response->getBody();
```

is the way to get the body and other people fixed their problems, but it's not working for me.

Obviously I'm still missing something here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `$client->request()` actually does the request (which is why it's returning an instance of `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response`) instead of building a request object to send later. You don't need to tell the client to send anything because it's already been sent; you just need to set the `$response` variable to the value of the call to `$client->request()`.

This can be seen in the [Body example](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/psr7.html#body) in their PSR7 documentation.

```
$response = $client->request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/get');
```

To build a request object manually, you will have to create an instance of `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request` using its constructor, as [documented under Requests](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/psr7.html#requests).

```
// Create a request using a completely custom HTTP method
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('MOVE', 'http://httpbin.org/move');

echo $request->getMethod();
// MOVE
```

Comment: Excellent!  thank you very much. I removed the send and now it is working as expected.

Comment: Glad to hear it!